# Call thread from another thread javafx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, java-threads

I have been trying to run two tasks on two threads and using their progress to be indicated on progress bar and progress indicator.

First task is copyTask and second is copy file.
The copyTask sends the file object to copyFile for file copy.
 But the problem is only a single file gets copied and the file count seems to be correct.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author ANIL
 */
public class ProgressIndicateController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ProgressIndicator uploadIndicator;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar uploadBar;
    @FXML
    private TextArea errTxt;
    @FXML
    private Label uploadTxt;

    File f;
    Thread parent,child;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @FXML
    private Label sizeTXT;

//    private CopyTask copyTask;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO

        // Unbind progress property
        uploadBar.progressProperty().unbind();

        // Bind progress property
        uploadBar.progressProperty().bind(copyFile.progressProperty());

        // Hủy bỏ kết nối thuộc tính progress
        uploadIndicator.progressProperty().unbind();

        // Bind progress property.
        uploadIndicator.progressProperty().bind(copyTask.progressProperty());

        // Unbind text property for Label.
        uploadTxt.textProperty().unbind();

        // Bind the text property of Label
        // with message property of Task
        uploadTxt.textProperty().bind(copyTask.messageProperty());

        // Unbind text property for Label.
        sizeTXT.textProperty().unbind();

        // Bind the text property of Label
        // with message property of Task
        sizeTXT.textProperty().bind(copyFile.messageProperty());

        // When completed tasks
        copyTask.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, //
                new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                List<File> copied = copyTask.getValue();
                uploadTxt.textProperty().unbind();
                uploadTxt.setText("Copied: " + copied.size());
            }
        });
        copyFile.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, //
                new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                File copied = copyFile.getValue();
                sizeTXT.textProperty().unbind();
                sizeTXT.setText("Copied: " + copied.getAbsolutePath());
            }

        });

        // Start the Task.
       parent= new Thread(copyTask);
       parent.start();

    }
    Task<List<File>> copyTask = new Task<List<File>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<File> call() throws Exception {
            File dir = new File("F:");
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            int count = files.length;

            List<File> copied = new ArrayList<File>();
            int i = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    this.copy(file);
                    copied.add(file);
                }
                i++;
                this.updateProgress(i, count);
            }
            return copied;
        }

        private void copy(File file) throws Exception {

            this.updateMessage("Copying: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            f = file;
            child=new Thread(copyFile);            
            child.start();
            this.wait();

        }
    };
    Task<File> copyFile = new Task<File>() {
        @Override
        protected File call() throws Exception {
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            File dest=null;

                String name=f.getName();
                dest=new File("D:\\OUTPUT\\"+name);
                is = new FileInputStream(f);
                os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                double i=0.0;
                double l=f.length();
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    i+=length;
                    this.updateMessage("Copying: " + i +" bytes of " + l);
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);                     
                    this.updateProgress(i, l);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                is.close();
                os.close();
                this.notifyAll();
                return dest;
            }


    };
}
```

New Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author ANIL
 */
public class ProgressIndicateController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ProgressIndicator uploadIndicator;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar uploadBar;
    @FXML
    private TextArea errTxt;
    @FXML
    private Label uploadTxt;

    @FXML
    private Label sizeTXT;

    CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    final SimpleDoubleProperty prog1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    final SimpleDoubleProperty prog2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    final SimpleStringProperty text1 = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    final SimpleStringProperty text2 = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    final SimpleStringProperty err = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO


        // Unbind progress property
        uploadBar.progressProperty().unbind();

        // Bind progress property
        uploadBar.progressProperty().bind(prog2);

        // Hủy bỏ kết nối thuộc tính progress
        uploadIndicator.progressProperty().unbind();

        // Bind progress property.
        uploadIndicator.progressProperty().bind(prog1);

        // Unbind text property for Label.
        uploadTxt.textProperty().unbind();

        // Bind the text property of Label
        // with message property of Task
        uploadTxt.textProperty().bind(text1);

        // Unbind text property for Label.
        sizeTXT.textProperty().unbind();

        // Bind the text property of Label
        // with message property of Task
        sizeTXT.textProperty().bind(text2);

        //When completed tasks
        errTxt.textProperty().unbind();

        errTxt.textProperty().bind(err);

        // Start the Task.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File dir = new File("F:");
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                int count = files.length;                
                int i = 0;
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isFile()) {
                        try {

                            text1.setValue("Copying: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

                            InputStream is = null;
                            OutputStream os = null;
                            File dest = null;

                            String name = file.getName();
                            dest = new File("D:\\OUTPUT\\" + name);
                            is = new FileInputStream(file);
                            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int length;
                            double j = 0.0;
                            double l = file.length();
                            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                j += length;
                                text2.setValue("Copying: " + j + " bytes of " + l);
                                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                prog2.setValue(j / l);
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                            is.close();
                            os.close();

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            err.setValue(ex.toString());
                        }

                        i++;
                        prog1.setValue(i / count);
                    }

                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: a `wait` (and `notifyAll`) must happen in a block `synchronized` on the monitor object.

Comment: try using `CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier (2);`

Comment: Why do you need the second thread? What do you think `this.wait()` does: are you just trying to wait for the second thread (with `copyFile`) to complete?

Comment: yes. Im trying to display the file copy progress on progressbar while keeping the first thread to wait for the copy to complete.

Comment: If the first thread is just going to wait for the second thread to complete, you should just do everything on one thread. I.e. instead of `new Thread(copyFile); this.wait();` just do `copyFile.call();`. But also note that you can only use a `Task` once: so you cannot do this with the same task in a loop, you need to create a new task each time.

Comment: @James_D as u told, i did that and even used this as a reference[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153866/javafx-code-to-display-progress-of-another-running-thread  but the copying process is going on but it is not reflected on prograss indicator.

Comment: Are you binding the progress indicator each time you create a new task?